# Are there anyway to DllImport function from native dll loaded into RAM as byte array?

Tags: c#, runtime, arrays, dllimport, native-code

No matter how weird it sounds, I need it O_o
Well, the another solution, if it possible to load native DLL as byte array into RAM, but call function from there without DllImport >_<

Kinda this way:

```
byte[] dll_data = File.RealAllBytes("native.dll"); //this is just example, in real architecture bytes comes from another source and should never be stored on HDD
//uhh... ohh... do something to call exported function named "WeirdNativeFunction"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to call the appropriate methods to load the native DLL into the calling process.  The [MemoryModule](https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule) project on GitHub provides a (native) API for handling this, which you could use from a C++/CLI project.

Once you had the `native.dll` loaded into the process, you could use [P/Invoke to call GetProcAddress](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getprocaddress) to get a handle to the `"WeirdNativeFunction"`, and  [`Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdx6dyyh.aspx) to convert it to a managed delegate, which you could then call.

Answer (score -1):

Someone ported MemoryModule to c#:
https://github.com/dretax/DynamicDllLoader

Here is an example from the project how to use it:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int AddDelegate(int a, int b);

static void RunAdd(byte[] dllBytes)
{
    DLLFromMemory dll = new DLLFromMemory(dllBytes);

    AddDelegate addFunc = dll.GetDelegateFromFuncName<AddDelegate>("Add");
    Console.WriteLine("Calling add(1, 2): " + addFunc(1, 2) + "\n");

    dll.Close();
}
```

but the most recent fork including TLS-support seems to be:
https://github.com/schellingb/DLLFromMemory-net